# AmbiguousMatchException on controller routes

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I am trying to build a basic mini project on .NET Core Web API for basic operations like: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE.

I have the following code in my `WeatherForecastController` which triggers an `AmbiguousMatchException`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace Webdemo.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]/[Action]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
     static List<string> names = new List<string>()
         {
            "c","a","b"
         };
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return names;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get (int id) {
            return names[id];
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
            names.Add(value);
        }
        [HttpPut]
        public void Put(int id,[FromBody]string value)
        {
            names[id] = value;
        }
       [HttpDelete]
        public void Delete(int id) 
        {
            names.RemoveAt(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: error:                                                                                           
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Webdemo.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (Webdemo)
Webdemo.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (Webdemo)
Webdemo.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Post (Webdemo)
Webdemo.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Put (Webdemo)
Webdemo.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Delete (Webdemo)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.
>
> ```
>     [HttpGet]
>     public IEnumerable<string> Get()
>     {
>         return names;
>     }
>     [HttpGet]
>     public string Get (int id) {
>         return names[id];
>     }
> ```

The issue is related to the above code, try to add a placeholder variable for the unique identifier, change the code as below:

```
    // GET: api/<WeatherForecastController>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return names;
    }
    // GET: api/<WeatherForecastController>/1
    [HttpGet("{id}")] //When this action is invoked, the value of "{id}" in the URL is provided to the method in its id parameter
    public string Get (int id) {
        return names[id];
    }
```

**Edit**:

Articles about passing parameters with Asp.net Core API:

[Tutorial: Create a web API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody)

[Multiple GET And POST Methods In ASP.NET Core Web API](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/9db02aa1-c193-421e-94d0-926e440ed297.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your `Get` methods match the same endpoint only with a different set of parameters.
You can work around that by changing the name of one the methods, for example the second `Get` method could become `GetSingle` as it seems to fetch a single entry from the `names` list by its `id`.

You can do it like:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetSingle (int id) 
{
    return names[id];
}
```